# Image annotation different

Tags: xcode, mapkitannotation

I created a map view with different annotation and a search. I can not attribute a different image according to the pin. I also have another concern, when I do a search it removes a pin to put it on the new place sought. Below is the code of a young coder. In advance thank you for your help.

```
import MapKit
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!

    var searchController:UISearchController!
    var annotation:MKAnnotation!
    var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
    var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
    var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
    var error:NSError!
    var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
    var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

    var coordinates: [[Double]]!
    var name:[String]!

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

    @IBAction func showSearchBar(_ sender: Any) {

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.MapView.delegate = self

        var Tirta = CustomPointAnnotation()
        Tirta.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-8.415162, 115.315360)
        Tirta.title = "Tirta Empul"
        Tirta.imageName = "PaConseil.png"

        var Goa = CustomPointAnnotation()
        Goa.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-8.551313, 115.468865)
        Goa.title = "Goa Lawah"
        Goa.imageName = "PaMecontent.png"

        MapView.addAnnotation(Tirta)
        MapView.addAnnotation(Goa)

        // 3
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -8.670458199999999, longitude: 115.2126293), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2, longitudeDelta: 2))
        self.MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func MapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        print("delegate called")

        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"

        var AnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if AnnotationView == nil {
            AnnotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            AnnotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            AnnotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        }

        let CustomPointAnnotation = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
        AnnotationView?.image = UIImage(named:CustomPointAnnotation.imageName)

        return AnnotationView
    }

    class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
        var imageName: String!
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
        //1
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if self.MapView.annotations.count != 0{
            annotation = self.MapView.annotations[0]
            self.MapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
        //2
        localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
        localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
        localSearch.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

            if localSearchResponse == nil{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
            //3
            self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text
            self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


            self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
            self.MapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
            self.MapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
        }

    }
}


import Foundation
import MapKit

class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {

    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var name: String!
    var imageName: UIImage!

    init(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinates = coordinates
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can not attribute a different image according to the pin" I can see you saying `AnnotationView?.image = UIImage(named:CustomPointAnnotation.imageName)` so where are things going wrong?

Comment: The problem is that I do not have images of different annotations. I remain on a traditional pin

Comment: Okay, so did you set a breakpoint to see if that line is being executed?

Comment: Hello, actually the method written correctly changes everything. It works, great thank you. On the other hand I can not solve the problem of research. If I launch the search on a new city, it removes and moves the first pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you've updated Xcode so that you are now using Swift 3. Well then, the problem is that this method is never being executed:

```
func MapView(mapView: MKMapView!, 
    viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
```

... and the reason is that that is not its correct "signature". That method is now defined [like this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
    viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

Comment: Another problem, unrelated, is that you've accidentally "buried" your `func didReceiveMemoryWarning()` inside that other method.